# Setting the value of REM for all the properties in CSS

Tags: html, css

I would like to use rem everywhere (read for all the possible properties) in my site. However, using the default rem - px conversion rate isn't quite intuitive :

```
10px = 0.625rem
12px = 0.75rem
14px = 0.875rem
16px = 1rem (base)
18px = 1.125rem
20px = 1.25rem
24px = 1.5rem
30px = 1.875rem
32px = 2rem
```

Thus I am using `html { font-size: 62.5%; }` which will set 1rem = 10px for the font size. 
How does that work however if I want to set the margin/padding/border/... to that conversion rate as well ?

Thanks !

Comment: I do and I can indeed. But I would like to set 1rem = 10px for the margin too.

Comment: My question is actually about how setting 1rem = 10 px for all the properties ?

Comment: It seems to work, even though your answer wasn't clear the first time (and you did edit after I did answer). Thanks anyway mate !

Answer (score 23, accepted):

We've covered this in comments, but essentially the answer is to set the *base* font size to 10px rather than 62.5%.

```
html { font-size: 10px; }
```

Now, all your rem values work from 1rem = 10px. which mean your calculations actually got a lot simpler.

- 1.5rem = 15px
- 2rem   = 20px

...and so on.

Now `margin: 1rem` really does mean `margin: 10px`.

Comment: This is not recommended as this removes the user's ability to override the browser's root font size.

Answer (score 14):

Setting your font-size at root level using an absolute unit overwrites the user’s browser settings (default is medium [16px]). It is better to use relative unit. eg.

```
// scss comments: use /* in css */
// 1rem = 10px
// 62.5*16px(base) = 10px
html {
  font-size: 62.5%; // will work when user change browser font
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. More friendly for the visually impaired users